# Going to Cemetery on a yarhzeit

Tags: cemetery-grave

I heard before from a Talmud Chacham that if someone has a yahrzeit and they are unable to go to the kever where the person is buried then there is still and "inyun" of going to a Cemetery on that day. Is there any source for this?

(I heard this on my Grandfathers yarhzeit when I went along with a Talmud Chacham (who was then a Rebbe of mine in Yeshiva) and a friend to Har HaZasim in Yerushalayim on someone else's yarhzeit. I mentioned to the Talmud Chacham that it was my Grandfathers yahrzeit at which he told me this idea of going to another cemetery on the day of a yarhzeit if you are unable to get to the one where the person is buried.)

Comment: I remember hearing that the AR"I prohibited visiting the cemetery except when escorting a dead body.

Comment: @SethJ:  So why does everyone go to the kevers of gedolim?

Comment: @BruceJames It was presented as perhaps the greatest irony in Jewish history. His is probably the most-visited Kever ever.

Comment: @SethJ This needs a strong mareh makom....And Rashbi is probably most-visted

Comment: @Yehoshua, true, he had a head start.

Comment: @BruceJames Maybe they don't hold of the AR"I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Kav HaYahser Perek 71](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40032&st=&pgnum=190)

He writes there the following:

> ״ויבא עד חברון״ ופירש״י: ״מלמד שהלך כלב על קברי האבות להתפלל שם שיהיה
>   ניצול מעצת מרגלים״. ומכאן נתפשט המנהג יפה שבישראל שאנחנו הולכים על
>   קברי אבות להתפלל ביום שמת בו אביו או אמו, ואף אם הוא במקום אחר באותו
>   הפעם ביאר־צייט ואינו במקום ששוכב שם אביו או אמו מ״מ כשהולך על שאר קברי
>   ישראל להתפלל מ״מ מתעוררים כל הנשמות שבגן עדן באותה התפלה וסדנא דארעא
>   חד הוא, שהקב״ה גזר כן להיות נפשות הצדיקים מצויין על הקברות לטובת ישראל
>   שיהיו שומעין לתחינות ותפלות ישראל הבאים להתפלל על הקברות

Essentially saying that even if someone is found on the day of the yahrzeit of a mother or father in a different place (not where they are buried) then there is still an inyun to go to other kavarim and daven. Through his tefillah can wake up all of the Neshamos in Gan Eden...